# כל מקדש שביעי כראוי לו and כל שומר שבת כדת why are we saying the same thing twice

Tags: shabbat-songs, kol-mikadesh

כל מקדש שביעי כראוי לו and כל שומר שבת כדת why are we saying the same thing in diffrent words twice it is the same idea what does one statment say that the other does not what does it add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former describes fulfillment of "[Zachor](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/shabbat.html#Zachor)," the latter of "[Shamor](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/shabbat.html#Shamor)."